# asp.net label wont write 2<B?

Tags: asp.net, label

Simple aspx page

(ValidateRequest="false")

I want the label to write:

```
2<B             //no spaces
```

I've tried:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1"  Text="2<B" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2"  Text="2&lt;B" runat="server" />
```

Both output `2`

[image]

I've also tried:

```
<span ID="Label3"   >2&lt;B</span>
```

Which works!

But how can I tell the runat server label to write merely `2<B`?

Why he doesnt understand the `&gt;`?

### Edit:

Viewsource:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the View Source for the first two options.

Comment: The problem is <B should be < B. space between them otherwise it will assume it an html tag. Same when you do 2&lt;B should be 2&lt; B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just html encode the `&lt;` again (`&amp;lt;`)

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='2&amp;lt;B' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it on the server side

```
Label1.Text = "2&lt;B"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Label` does **not** encode the output. If you want output to be encoded, you should use a `Literal` with `Mode` set to `Encode` or encode it yourself using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`:

```
this.Label1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("2<B");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like typing 2 & l t ; B, then you can use Literal with Mode=Encode:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="2<B" Mode="Encode"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

put space between < and B and both works
 like

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1"  Text="2 < B" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2"  Text="2 &lt; B" runat="server" />
```

**Update**: when you put `<B` this way it assumes incomplete html tag.So it won't render it. To render it either you should use space between them or as suggested use literal control or use

```
     HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">2&lt;B</asp:Label>
```